# What is the maclaurin series of $\dfrac{4x^5}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

After 1st derivative its getting more complicated.
Is there a easier way to calculate is?
Please be patient with me because math is not my prime subject.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You can use that $1/(1-x^2) = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots$.

Comment: Oh boy, now i feel stupid for asking such a trivial question .-. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bear in mind that the suggested expansion is only valid for $|x|<1$.